# Directive to Directive Communication in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So I have this filter directive:

```angular
app.directive('filter', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        callFunc: '&'
    },
    template:
            '   <div>' +
            '       <div ng-transclude></div>' +
            '   </div>',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
        this.getData = function() {
            $scope.callFunc()
        }
    }
  }   
});

app.directive('positions', function(){
  return {
    require: '^filter', 
    scope: {
        selectedPos: '='
    },
    template:
            '  Positions: {{selectedPos}}' +
            '  <ul>' +
            '   <li ng-repeat="pos in positions">' +
            '           <a href="#" ng-click="setPosition(pos); posRegData()">{{pos.name}}</a></a>' +
            '       </li>' +
            '  </ul>',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
          $scope.positions = [
            {name: '1'},
            {name: '2'},
            {name: '3'},
            {name: '4'},
            {name: '5'}
          ];
          $scope.selectedPos = $scope.positions[0].name;
          $scope.setPosition = function(pos){
            $scope.selectedPos = pos.name;
          };

    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, filterCtrl) {
        scope.posRegData = function() {
            filterCtrl.getData();
        }
    }
  }   
})
```

And the controller:

```
app.controller('keyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var key = this;
  key.callFunc = function() {
    key.value = key.selectedPos;
    console.log(key.selectedPos)
  }
}]);
```

The main question is why the `key.selectedPos` in the controller get's the right value only on the second click?

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Cp4rsqEh6FJao6PowNq?p=preview) replicating my issue.

---

One way of doing it is to send a param when calling `callFunc()`

Then, I update the func in the ctrl: `key.callFunc = function(filterParams)`, but also, I am updating the passed method `call-func="key.callFunc(filterParams)`

Then in `filter directive` I change getData method to:

```
this.getData = function(val) {
  $scope.callFunc({filterParams: val})
}
```

In `positions directive` I pass the value that I need:

```
scope.posRegData = function() {
  filterCtrl.getData({position: scope.selectedPos});
}
```

Finally, in `keyCtrl` I get the value like this:

```
key.callFunc = function(filterParams) {
  key.value = filterParams.position;
  console.log(filterPrams.position)
}
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ibWobKiYXMMdzFwl0dJS?p=preview) demonstrating this attempt.

The question in this case is if this is a good way of doing it, keeping in mind it's within a very large application.

Comment: If you want to share data between controllers or directives.
Using a service is almost always the best route to take

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because how isolated scopes work. The parent scope (the controller in your case) will be updated when the digest cycle runs, which is after your `ng-click` function called the `callFunc`. So you can put your `callFunc` code in a `$timeout` and it will work (but will cause another digest cycle).

Another solution will be to put the value in an object, so when you change the object the controller (which have the reference) will see the update immediately:

In the controller:

```
key.selectedPos = { value: {}};

key.callFunc = function() {
    key.value = key.selectedPos.value;  
    console.log(key.selectedPos.value)
}
```

In the directive:

```
$scope.selectedPos.value = $scope.positions[0].name;
$scope.setPosition = function(pos){
    $scope.selectedPos.value = pos.name;
};
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vi1NI7TiCy6v5K0Ey0OP?p=preview).

Comment: I was going to talk about $scope.$apply() but i know it's not a good practice. Thx for the object trick. I'll keep that in mind.